# Error creating code coverage report with JaCoCo

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, surefire

I'm trying to add report generation for code coverage using JaCoCo. The project is using Maven, so i have jacoco maven plugin configured like this:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And surefire plugin like this:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${argLine} -XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/selenium/**/*.java</exclude>
                <excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But in the end of running

> mvn clean package

i'm getting such error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946:report (report) on project LMS: An error has occurred in JaCoCo Test report generation. Error while creating report: invalid literal/length code -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

The thing is, on another project same thing works like a charm. I couldn't find a solution online. Anyone has any ideas?

Using -e switch i get the following errors:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946:report (report) on project LMS: An error has occurred in JaCoCo Test report generation.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An error has occurred in JaCoCo Test report generation.
        at org.jacoco.maven.AbstractReportMojo.execute(AbstractReportMojo.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: Error while creating report: invalid literal/length code
        at org.jacoco.maven.AbstractReportMojo.executeReport(AbstractReportMojo.java:196)
        at org.jacoco.maven.AbstractReportMojo.execute(AbstractReportMojo.java:178)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid literal/length code
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:193)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
        at org.jacoco.core.internal.ContentTypeDetector.readInt(ContentTypeDetector.java:95)
        at org.jacoco.core.internal.ContentTypeDetector.determineType(ContentTypeDetector.java:68)
        at org.jacoco.core.internal.ContentTypeDetector.<init>(ContentTypeDetector.java:63)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:172)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeZip(Analyzer.java:246)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:178)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:208)
        at org.jacoco.maven.BundleCreator.createBundle(BundleCreator.java:78)
        at org.jacoco.maven.AbstractReportMojo.createReport(AbstractReportMojo.java:219)
        at org.jacoco.maven.AbstractReportMojo.executeReport(AbstractReportMojo.java:193)
        ... 23 more
```

Comment: Make sure you're using Jacoco's latest version. Also, it might be a good idea to try running Maven with the -e switch, as it suggests.

Comment: I'm using the latest version, I also tried running with -e switch, i'll put the result in the question now

Answer (score 8):

I once faced this problem as well. It seems to be related to the Jacoco analyzer not being able to parse some resources (that were presumably the git submodules or a zip/binary within them). Simply ignoring that path of the resources folder for this task fixed the problem.

See: https://github.com/devhub-tud/devhub/commit/c21607d753fbac1ba26e8b14d4ba84f4487620f8

And:
https://github.com/devhub-tud/devhub/tree/master/src/main/resources/static